# Haskell substring testing

Tags: haskell

When I use `sub_string("abberr","habberyry")` , it returns True, when obviously it should be False. The point of the function is to search for the first argument within the second one. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
sub_string :: (String, String) -> Bool 
sub_string(_,[]) = False
sub_string([],_) = True
sub_string(a:x,b:y) | a /= b = sub_string(a:x,y)
                    | otherwise = sub_string(x,y)
```

Comment: (In Haskell it is preferred to take two arguments separated by a space rather than pass a pair as an argument.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you need to switch your first two lines. `_` will match `[]` and this will matter when you're matching, say, `substring "abc" "abc"`. Secondly, it is idiomatic Haskell to write a function with two arguments instead of one with a pair argument. So your code should start out:

```
substring :: String -> String -> Bool 
substring [] _ = True
substring _ [] = False
substring needle (h : aystack)
    | ...
```

Now we get to the tricky case where both of these lists are not empty. Here's the problem with recursing on `substring as bs`: you'll get results like `"abc"` being a substring of `"axbxcx"` (because `"abc"` will match `'a'` first, then will look for `"bc"` in the rest of the string; the substring algorithm will then skip past the `'x'` to look for `"bc"` in `"bxcx"`, which will match `'b'` and look for `"c"` in `"xcx"`, which will return `True`.

Instead your condition needs to be more thorough. If you're willing to use functions from `Data.List` this is:

```
    | isPrefixOf needle (h : aystack) = True
    | otherwise = substring needle aystack
```

Otherwise you need to write your own `isPrefixOf`, for example:

```
isPrefixOf needle haystack = needle == take (length needle) haystack
```

Comment: "(h : aystack)" - very clever.

Comment: I've totally stolen that from PHP, where they introduce arguments named `$needle` and `$haystack` to show the order of the arguments. Idiomatic Haskell would probably instead be `type Needle = String` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Let me give you hints on why it's not working:

- your function consumes "abber" and "habber" of the input stings on the initial phase.
- Now "r" and "yry" is left.

And "r" is a subset of "yry". So it returns `True`. To illustrate a more simple example of your problem:

```
*Main> sub_string("rz","rwzf")
True
```

Comment: How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

As Sibi already pointed out, your function tests for *subsequence*. Review the previous exercise, it is probably `isPrefixof` [(hackage documentation)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#g:12), which is just a fancy way of saying [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29), which looks very similar to the function you wrote.
If that is not the previous exercise, do that now!

Then write `sub_string` in terms of `isPrefixOf`:

```
sub_string (x, b:y) = isPrefixOf ... ?? ???
```

Fill in the dots and "?" yourself.